# let contentview = ContentView () receives error Use of unresolved identifier 'ContentView' in SceneDelegate

Tags: xcode

I can't figure out this error. I am running Xcode 11.5 on a macOS Catalina 10.5 I had this working before I upgraded Xcode. The file `ContentView.swift` is in the project and yet the statement `let contentView = ContentView ()` results in the above error. I have tried searching for a solution to no avail. I am relatively knew to coding in Xcode/swift. There are no other errors. The project was originally on an older MacOS a model late 2008. However, I am sure I had it working on my new Mac - that is until I updated Xcode and Catalina MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue in my project, although the build resulting in "Build Succeeded" and I could still run my iOS app. I had a folder named "Views" and had moved "ContentView" to this folder because I wanted to organize all of my views in this folder. "SceneDelegate" remained in the base project folder. However, if I moved "ContentView" from the "Views" folder back to the base project folder and rebuilt, the error would go away. Then I would move it back to the "Views" folder and it would reappear! It was very frustrating. Finally, I left it in the "Views" folder (where I wanted it) and decided to simply try restarting XCode. I did this, and it rebuilt successfully.